# How do you make evenly sized swimlanes in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I've resized my swimlane/poollane container to a larger width, but now the last lane is much wider than the first two. This also occurs when I increase or decrease the width of an individual pool lane, of course.

Is there a way to automatically make all of the lanes the same width as each other, evenly distributed in their container? Or do I have to size them manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you can't really do this. The best you can do is put content in the swimlanes that are the same size. The swimlanes then resize to fit what you've put inside.

You can tell draw.io to resize your swimlane by selecting it, then Autosize from the Arrange menu

Answer (score 0):

Swimlanes should automatically resize their child cells when made longers, if they don't that's a bug.

[image]

Comment: I'm talking about getting their widths to be equal. Their lengths are fine and do match up to each other. I'll try to clarify my question.